# Need A help in understanding a step in matrix representation of bounded linear operators.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

Israel Gohberg book that is called "Basic operator theory" said that:

Suppose $A \in L(H),$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\phi_{1}, \phi_{2},....$, then for $x \in H, x = \sum_{j} <x,\phi_{j}> \phi_{j}.$ It follows from the linearity and continuity of $A$, applied to the sequence of partial sums of this series, that $$Ax = \sum_{j}<x,\phi_{j}> A\phi_{j}......(1)$$

But I did not understand the last statement, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \in H$ let $s_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n<x,\phi_j> \phi_j$. Then $s_n(x) \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore we get

$Ax=A( \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n(x))=\lim_{n \to \infty}A(s_n(x))=$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n<x,\phi_j> A\phi_j=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}<x,\phi_j> A\phi_j$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $<x,\phi_j>$is a scalar.
Since $A$ is linear, then $A(cx) = cA(x)$ for every scalar $c$. So, in the sum:
$$ \sum_{j} A (<x,\phi_j> \phi_j) = A(<x,\phi_1> \phi_1) + \cdots + A(<x,\phi_n> \phi_n) = <x,\phi_1> A(\phi_1) + \cdots + <x,\phi_n> A(\phi_n) = \sum_j <x, \phi_j> A(\phi_j)$$